# Thrift: the import javax.annotation cannot be resolved

Tags: import, annotations, thrift

I use Eclipse Mars (M1) as my IDE. Today, I generated my service's Java code using Apache Thrift 0.9.2 (latest stable version) for an Android project. This version (unlke version 0.9.1) uses the "Generated" annotation from javax.annotation package, for adding some extractable documentation. It adds a line like the following line before each generated class:

@Generated(value = "Autogenerated by Thrift Compiler (0.9.2)", date = "2014-11-30")

But surprisingly, Eclipse complains about the package javax.annotation. It throws the error "the import javax.annotation cannot be resolved". My project's Java compiler compliance level is 1.6, and its minimum Android API version is API 8 (Android 2.2). How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately **most of packages under javax.* are not included in Android's JDK**, therefore you need to add those that you need, manually. [Here](https://code.google.com/p/dalvik/wiki/JavaxPackages) the reason for not including these packages is explained.

Unluckily, there are several versions of javax.annotation package available for download, some of which don't contain the "Generated" annotation class (javax.annotation.generated). Fortunately [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxannotationjar.htm) jar file does include that specific annotation class. So if you don't use any build system like Gradle, Ant, or Maven, all you have to do is to include the .jar file in a directory in your project (e.g. lib/) and then add this jar library to your buildpath. If you use Ant, then follow the first link.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by adding this dependency to my build.gradle file

```
compile group: 'javax.annotation', name: 'javax.annotation-api', version: '1.3.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I just stumbled upon it and I thought I’d share an alternative solution to your problem.

You can simply generate your Java thrift files with the option: `generated_annotations=suppress`
The generator will produce `.java` files without javax annotation.